# Remove .html extension excluding one directory

Tags: php

I am using the following code to remove the .html suffix and would like to exclude it for my /billing directory. How can I do this?

All the files in my /billing directory have the .php extension

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a RewriteCond that excludes the rule in the billing directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/billing/
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: What I have done on my .htaccess is `RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.html [L]` on rewrite rule where condition is similar as @yoavmatchulsky